# How to pass id from ajax to controller - Laravel & Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

Currently, i am on the show page that is i am running the function `show` as in my controller so my url is showing like `dashboard/1/people` in the url address bar. Now, when i click on a person, it routes to a different page and that is where `getPeople` is called.

How can i get the id of the person i clicked which is `1` from the ajax request in the `scripts` and pass to my controller?

PS: At the moment, i have hardcoded `1` in the ajax request but i want it to be dynamic please

How do i get this done?

**Script**

```
 datatable = $('#table').DataTable({

                "ajax": "{{ route('dashboard/1/people') }}",
                "columns": [
                    {data: 'check', name: 'check'},      

                ],
```

**Controller**

```
  public function show($id)
     {
            $class = Class::whereId($id)->first();

         return view('show');
     }



     public function getPeople($id)
         {
            $get_id = $id;
            $class = Class::whereId($get_id)->first();
            $people = $class->peoples()->get();
            return Datatables::of($people)->addColumn('action', function ($ppl) {
                //return 
    })->make(true);        


         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

**In your `getPeople` method store the id in a `session` variable:**

```
 public function getPeople($id)
     {
        $get_id = $id;
        //using session helper method
        session(['show_id' => $id]);
        $class = Class::whereId($get_id)->first();
        $people = $class->peoples()->get();
        return Datatables::of($people)->addColumn('action', function ($ppl) {
            //return 
        })->make(true);        
     }
```

**and then access it in you ajax code:**

```
 datatable = $('#table').DataTable({

                "ajax": "{{ route('dashboard/'.session('show_id').'/people') }}",
                "columns": [
                    {data: 'check', name: 'check'},      

                ],
```

Answer (score 0):

DataTable ajax allows yo to pass extra parameters in object format just like this:

```
datatable = $('#table').DataTable({    
        "ajax": {
            "type": "GET",
            data:{id: my_id_var},
            "url": "my_route"
        }
    }
```

And in your function just get the Request var

```
public function getPeople(Request $request){
            $get_id = $request->id;
            $class = Class::whereId($get_id)->first();
            $people = $class->peoples()->get();
            return Datatables::of($people)->addColumn('action', function ($ppl) {
                //return 
    })->make(true);        
}
```

More Information in [Sorce Page](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data)